# myCall.enqueue(new Callback() ){.....} is not giving any response

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am making one adforest classified alike app in my android studio and 
        below is the splash screen activity which executes first when i click on app icon but after that next activity does not open...progress bar on splash screen keeps on rotating but it is not openning next activity !!

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

                Activity activity;
                SettingsMain setting;
                JSONObject jsonObjectSetting;

                boolean isRTL = false;

                public static JSONObject jsonObjectAppRating, jsonObjectAppShare;

                public static boolean gmap_has_countries = false, app_show_languages = false;
                public static JSONArray app_languages;
                public static String languagePopupTitle, languagePopupClose, gmap_countries;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
                    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
                    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1; //0.85 small size, 1 normal size, 1,15 big etc

                    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);

                    activity = this;
                    setting = new SettingsMain(this);


                    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                    if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {

                        setting.setUserLogin("0");

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
                        editor.apply();
                    }

                    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                        getSupportActionBar().hide();

                    }

                    try {
                        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                                "com.call4site.nearhaat",
                                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
                            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

                        }
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
                    {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    if (SettingsMain.isConnectingToInternet(this)) {

                        adforest_getSettings(this);

                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreen.this);
                        alert.setTitle(setting.getAlertDialogTitle("error"));
                        alert.setCancelable(false);
                        alert.setMessage(setting.getAlertDialogMessage("internetMessage"));
                        alert.setPositiveButton(setting.getAlertOkText(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                SplashScreen.this.recreate();
                            }
                        });
                        alert.show();
                    }
                }

                public void adforest_getSettings(final Context context) {

                    RestService restService =
                            UrlController.createService(RestService.class);

                    Call<ResponseBody> myCall = restService.getSettings(UrlController.AddHeaders(this));

                    myCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() { 
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> responseObj) {
                            try {
                                if (responseObj.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.d("info settings Responce", "" + responseObj.toString());

                                    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseObj.body().string());
                                    Log.d("info settings object", "" + response.getJSONObject("data"));
                                    if (response.getBoolean("success")) {
                                        jsonObjectSetting = response.getJSONObject("data");

                                        setting.setMainColor(jsonObjectSetting.getString("main_color"));

                                        isRTL = jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("is_rtl");
                                        setting.setRTL(isRTL);
                                        setting.setAlertDialogTitle("error", jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("internet_dialog").getString("title"));
                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("internetMessage", jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("internet_dialog").getString("text"));
                                        setting.setAlertOkText(jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("internet_dialog").getString("ok_btn"));
                                        setting.setAlertCancelText(jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("internet_dialog").getString("cancel_btn"));

                                        setting.setAlertDialogTitle("info", jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("alert_dialog").getString("title"));
                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("confirmMessage", jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("alert_dialog").getString("message"));

                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("waitMessage", jsonObjectSetting.getString("message"));

                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("search", jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("search").getString("text"));
                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("catId", jsonObjectSetting.getString("cat_input"));
                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("location_type", jsonObjectSetting.getString("location_type"));
                                        setting.setAlertDialogMessage("gmap_lang", jsonObjectSetting.getString("gmap_lang"));
                                        setting.setGoogleButn(jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("registerBtn_show").getBoolean("google"));
                                        setting.setfbButn(jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("registerBtn_show").getBoolean("facebook"));

                                        JSONObject alertDialog = jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("dialog").getJSONObject("confirmation");
                                        setting.setGenericAlertTitle(alertDialog.getString("title"));
                                        setting.setGenericAlertMessage(alertDialog.getString("text"));
                                        setting.setGenericAlertOkText(alertDialog.getString("btn_ok"));
                                        setting.setGenericAlertCancelText(alertDialog.getString("btn_no"));

                                        setting.isAppOpen(jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("is_app_open"));
                                        setting.checkOpen(jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("is_app_open"));
                                        setting.setGuestImage(jsonObjectSetting.getString("guest_image"));

                                        JSONObject jsonObjectLocationPopup = jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("location_popup");
                                        Log.d("info location_popup obj", "" + jsonObjectLocationPopup);
                                        setting.setLocationSliderNumber(jsonObjectLocationPopup.getInt("slider_number"));
                                        setting.setLocationSliderStep(jsonObjectLocationPopup.getInt("slider_step"));
                                        setting.setLocationText(jsonObjectLocationPopup.getString("text"));
                                        setting.setLocationBtnSubmit(jsonObjectLocationPopup.getString("btn_submit"));
                                        setting.setLocationBtnClear(jsonObjectLocationPopup.getString("btn_clear"));

                                        JSONObject jsonObjectLocationSettings = jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("gps_popup");
                                        setting.setShowNearby(jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("show_nearby"));
                                        Log.d("info gps_popup obj", "" + jsonObjectLocationSettings);
                                        setting.setGpsTitle(jsonObjectLocationSettings.getString("title"));
                                        setting.setGpsText(jsonObjectLocationSettings.getString("text"));
                                        setting.setGpsConfirm(jsonObjectLocationSettings.getString("btn_confirm"));
                                        setting.setGpsCancel(jsonObjectLocationSettings.getString("btn_cancel"));

                                        setting.setAdsPositionSorter(jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("ads_position_sorter"));

                                        setting.setBannerShow(false);
                                        setting.setAdsPosition("");
                                        setting.setBannerAdsId("");
                                        setting.setInterstitalShow(false);
                                        setting.setAdsInitialTime("");
                                        setting.setAdsDisplayTime("");
                                        setting.setInterstitialAdsId("");

                                        setting.setNotificationTitle("");
                                        setting.setNotificationMessage("");
                                        setting.setNotificationTitle("");

                                        if (setting.getAppOpen()) {
                                            setting.setNoLoginMessage(jsonObjectSetting.getString("notLogin_msg"));
                                        }

                                        setting.setFeaturedScrollEnable(jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("featured_scroll_enabled"));
                                        if (setting.isFeaturedScrollEnable()) {
                                            Log.d("info setting AutoScroll", jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("featured_scroll").toString());
                                            setting.setFeaturedScroolDuration(jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("featured_scroll").getInt("duration"));
                                            setting.setFeaturedScroolLoop(jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("featured_scroll").getInt("loop"));
                                        }

                                        jsonObjectAppRating = jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("app_rating");
                                        jsonObjectAppShare = jsonObjectSetting.getJSONObject("app_share");

                                        gmap_has_countries = jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("gmap_has_countries");
                                        if (gmap_has_countries) {
                                            gmap_countries = jsonObjectSetting.getString("gmap_countries");
                                        }
                                        app_show_languages = jsonObjectSetting.getBoolean("app_show_languages");

                                        if (app_show_languages) {
                                            languagePopupTitle = jsonObjectSetting.getString("app_text_title");
                                            languagePopupClose = jsonObjectSetting.getString("app_text_close");
                                            app_languages = jsonObjectSetting.getJSONArray("app_languages");

                                        }

                                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                //Do something after 100ms

                                                if (setting.getUserLogin().equals("0")) {
                                                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                                                    if (setting.isLanguageChanged()) {
                                                        if (isRTL)
                                                            updateViews("ur");
                                                        else {
                                                            updateViews("en");
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_enter, R.anim.left_out);
                                                } else {
                                                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                                                    if (setting.isLanguageChanged()) {
                                                        if (isRTL)
                                                            updateViews("ur");
                                                        else {
                                                            updateViews("en");
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                    setting.isAppOpen(false);
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_enter, R.anim.left_out);
                                                }

                                                if (app_show_languages && !setting.isLanguageChanged()) {
                                                    if (setting.getLanguageRtl()) {
                                                        updateViews("ur");
                                                    } else {
                                                        updateViews("en");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, 2000);
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(activity, response.get("message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            catch (IOException e) {     

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                            Log.d("info settings error", String.valueOf(t));
                            Log.d("info settings error", String.valueOf(t.getMessage() + t.getCause() + t.fillInStackTrace()));
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
                    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
                }

                private void updateViews(String languageCode) {
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, languageCode);
                }
            }
```

This is UrlController java class which uses to call retrofit api:

UrlController.java

```
            public class UrlController {
                    static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                            .build();
                private static String Purchase_code = "************************";
                private static String Custom_Security = "***********************";

                private static String url = "null";
                private static String Base_URL = "https://yourdomain.co.in/demo/";
                private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(Base_URL)
                                .client(okHttpClient)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

                private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

                public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass)
                {
                    url = retrofit.baseUrl().toString();
                    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
                }

                public static <S> S createService(
                        Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password, Context context)
                {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                        String authToken = Credentials.basic(username, password);

                        return createService(serviceClass, authToken, context);
                    }

                    return createService(serviceClass, null, null, context);
                }

                public static <S> S createService(
                        Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken, Context context)
                {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
                        AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor = new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken, context);


                        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor))
                        {
                            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

                            builder.client(httpClient.build());

                            retrofit = builder.build();

                        }

                    }

                    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
                }

                public static Map<String, String> AddHeaders(Context context) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    if (SettingsMain.isSocial(context)) {
                        map.put("AdForest-Login-Type", "social");
                    }

                    map.put("Purchase-Code", Purchase_code);
                    map.put("custom-security", Custom_Security);
                    map.put("Adforest-Request-From", "android");
                    map.put("Adforest-Lang-Locale", SettingsMain.getLanguageCode());
                    map.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    map.put("Cache-Control", "max-age=640000");
                    return map;
                }

                public static Map<String, String> UploadImageAddHeaders(Context context) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    if (SettingsMain.isSocial(context)) {
                        map.put("AdForest-Login-Type", "social");
                    }

                    map.put("Purchase-Code", Purchase_code);
                    map.put("custom-security", Custom_Security);
                    map.put("Adforest-Lang-Locale", SettingsMain.getLanguageCode());
                    map.put("Adforest-Request-From", "android");
                    map.put("Cache-Control", "max-age=640000");
                    return map;
                }
            }


        when it executes:

        myCall.enqueue(new Callback() 
         {

public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> responseObj) 
  {

        //some code here

  } );

  @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) 
            {
              //some code here
            }






      It does not executes either the on response method or on Failure method. No error or exception in catch block. In android studio logcat debug mode it shows :
```

D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews:android.widget.LinearLayout{a73a5de V.E...... ......I. 0,0-580,115}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@eeef6d7
i don't understand the problem behind it...is this debug message is the cause due to which next activity not opening or it is happening due to something else??
    I am badly stuck here...not finding any way to move ahead !!

Comment: Did you try to debug? It might not be hitting `startActivity` line.

Comment: ya,i tried but it does not executing after mycall.enqueue(new Callback()) method..and this is the last debug message : D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews:android.widget.LinearLayout{a73a5de V.E...... ......I. 0,0-580,115}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@eeef6d7

Comment: Try adding a debug breakpoint in all your condition and see where it is hitting.

Comment: thankx Rick...error caught at onResponse() and following  response is coming : Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=https://yourdomain.co.in/myapp/settings/}